# Non-self signed certificate gives certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: ssl, go, ca

I have an API server using a non-self signed certificate issued by a respected CA. When I connect to this server I get the following error:

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I connect using a golang client using the `net/http` library. The certificate is properly configured as I do not get an error complaining about it.

I did not expect this error because I am using a CA. I am not getting the error when using a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not pass the intermediate CA certificate to the http server. The method `http.ListenAndServeTLS` requires the intermediate CA certificate in the same certificate file.

The fix was easy, just add the intermediate certificate of your CA in your certificate file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<YOUR OWN CERTIFICATE>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<INTERMEDIATE CA CERTIFICATE>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```